# RMarkdown: How to use hooks on individual chunks?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to use knitr hooks on individual chunks using the [datacamp/tutorial](https://github.com/datacamp/tutorial) package. As per the following [document](https://github.com/datacamp/tutorial/blob/baa9cc2139e785feee6a63cef1c4d5a970321da1/R/hooks.R), I get to set two options of `height` and `greedy` by using `tutorial::go_interactive(greedy=FALSE, height=500)`

How can I set different variables for individual chunks using `knitr_hooks`?

For eg., For the first chunk I want to set it up as `greedy=TRUE`, and for the second one, I want `greedy=FALSE`.

````
---
title: "Example Document"
author: "Your name here"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

Here's an example of a Python fiddle/

```{python}
a = 2
b = 3

print(a + b)
```


```{python}
x = 2
y = 3

print(x + y)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Found the answer [here](https://datacamp.github.io/tutorial/reference/go_interactive.html#arguments)

You have to set `tut = FALSE` on the chunk to knit it as a normal chunk.

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

Here's an example of a Python fiddle/

```{python}
a = 2
b = 3

print(a + b)
```


```{python, tut=FALSE}
x = 2
y = 3

print(x + y)
```
````